# mod_proxy isn't using the port defined in my balancermembers

Tags: apache, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I'm trying to set up my apache load balancer to proxy to the same backend clusters to apps running on different ports. The cluster definitions are like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://wordpress-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.10:80
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.11:80
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://corporate-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.10:81
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.11:81
</Proxy>
```

In the load balancer, one of the vhost needs to talk to both, so in the vhost definition I have:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
SSLProxyEngine On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /feed balancer://wordpress-cluster/feed lbmethod=byrequests
ProxyPassReverse /feed balancer://wordpress-cluster/feed

ProxyPass / balancer://corporate-cluster/ lbmethod=byrequests
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://corporate-cluster/
```

when requesting for '/' , I get the content served from the port 80 app, *not* the port 81 app.

Would anyone know on what is happening? it looks like this might be a case of overzealous worker sharing, but shouldn't specifying the different ports prevent that?

Is there something else I should do?

Forgot to mention: this is using apache 2.2.4-1 on a centos box.

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I still don't know what happened. Did 2 steps to fix my problem:
1) split the cluster into 2 1-machine clusters and things worked:

```
<Proxy balancer://wordpress-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.10:80
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://corporate-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.11:81
</Proxy>
```

But of course that killed balancing and failover support... *not good*

Second option, create dns aliases to ensure that the balancermembers looked different (even though they point to the same boxes:

```
<Proxy balancer://wordpress-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.10:80
    BalancerMember http://192.168.2.11:80
</Proxy>
<Proxy balancer://corporate-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://corp01:81
    BalancerMember http://corp02:81
</Proxy>
```

And voila! The setup is now working for me :)